# Can Web API get input from angular client for confirmation and continue execution?

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-web-api, angular6

In our system we allow users to save draft data (draft table) and then user can submit that data for final save (FinalData table) whenever he wants.

Now here is the case that multiple user can save draft as well as submit

- **if user1 has saved draft and user2 is submitting data**
- **then I want to check on server if draft present,**
- **if so then go to client for confirmation to delete that draft**

To achieve this i have this solution

```
Angular client                       Web api
getLatestModDate         <----------> return date
                          ------yes-> SaveData
latestDate > myData.date | 
                          ------no. do nothing
```

But I want something like

```
 Angular client                       Web api
 call api saveData <---------->      check latest date
                  getConfirmation
                  <-----------      latestDate > myData.date

                    ------yes-----> SaveData
 User confirmation | 
                    ---No-->do nothing
 -----------------------------------------------------------
                                    latestDate <= myData.date
                                    Delete draft and save data without confirmation
```

is there any way, API can get input from angular client and continue with the execution?

Comment: Not mid-request. The first request could fail with e.g. 409 Conflict, with a payload containing enough information for the UI to inform the user of their options. Depending on what they pick, that may mean a second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. I had to return one custom HTTPStatus to inform client operation needs user input, after user gives his input then it make another api call and save the data.